# Rgd: Dual Horizontal Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I look through the internet and saw quite a few sample of horizontal slider with a value.

E.g if I set max value as 100, pull left 10 sector, each sector minus 10.

What I wanna achieve is there is 2 slider

If I pull left on the top slider, the bottom slider will increment by the 1 sector.

E.g if top is 7000, below will be 3000 ( with a max value of 10000 ) etc.

Is there such dual slider implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 jQuery UI sliders (https://jqueryui.com/slider/#default) with the value of each tied to (1 - value of the other other) via the onchange event of the other (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change)